# Two-way Synchronization between SQL Server and LocalDB

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, synchronization, localdb

giving the fact that SQL Replication does not work with LocalDB and Sync Framework is not maintained anymore (wizard does not exist for VS 2013), what would be a good choice to implement a two-way synchronization between SQL Server and LocalDB:

- Hand coded: seems troublesome
- Sync Framework: hard coded
- Another framework

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SQL Server Merge Replication, is supported by SQL Server Express, which is free and has same specs as LocalDb